# Vim doesn't replicate normal mode instructions accurately

Tags: vim

I want to make a function which generates a block of text of variable line count.
The text should go as follows:

```
1.wav
2.wav
3.wav
4.wav
...
```

My function looks like this:

```
function Rename(howmany)

    normal i1.wav
    normal yy

    let iter = 1
    while iter < a:howmany
        normal pp0^Ayy "^A is generated from <Ctrl-V> <Ctrl-A>
        let iter += 1
    endwhile

endfunction
```

The text generated with `:call Rename(5)` looks like this:

```
1.wav
1.wav
2.wav
2.wav
3.wav
3.wav
4.wav
4.wav
5.wav
```

Notice the repeating segment. If I were to recreate the normal mode steps one at a time (`pp` - paste line, `0` - go to the start of the line, `^A` - increment the number, `yy` - yank the current line for further copying).

I made a quick fix which deletes every other line.

That fix looks like this:

```
function Rename(howmany)

    normal i1.wav
    normal yy

    let iter = 1
    while iter < a:howmany
        normal pp0yy
        let iter += 1
    endwhile

    normal gg

    let iter = 1
    while iter < a:howmany
        normal dd
        normal 
        let iter += 1
    endwhile

endfunction
```

Anyone know why this happens? And how I could fix this, so that I don't have to circumvent the main issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is easy to spot:

```
normal pp0^Ayy
       ^^
```

There is no `pp` pendant to `yy`, there is only `p`. Therefore, `pp` puts the text from the default register two times:

```
1.wav
1.wav
1.wav
```

and you only increment the second one:

```
1.wav
1.wav
2.wav
```

The next loop yanks the last line and puts it two times again:

```
1.wav
1.wav
2.wav
2.wav
2.wav
```

and so on…

Removing the extraneous `p` will fix the problem:

```
function! Rename(howmany)
    normal i1.wav
    normal yy
    let iter = 1
    while iter < a:howmany
        normal p0^Ayy
        let iter += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```